# PHP connecting using Xampp error(Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying connecting database however I am receiving this kind of error someone could fix this how?

[image]

I've attempted this as well, but the mistake remains.

```
<?php

$sname = 'localhost';   //server name properties name any
$user = 'root';   //server username 
$pass = '';   //server password
$db = 'database_new';   //database name

$db = new mysqli ('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die ("unable to connect");
echo "Successfully Connected";

?>
```

I looked in user accounts as well in xampp localhost there are no errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't have a `test` user in your users table

Comment: the database `database_new` is exist?

Comment: Hello yes, I have test and database_new created in the xampp database.

Comment: Your list of users clearly shows that there is no user called `test` in your database. In your call to `new PDO` you are passing in `$db` as the username argument, which I'd guess you didn't intend. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php